# ffmpeg Streaming from second X to icecast2

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, icecast

i try to stream a MP3 file to icecast2 with it's native bitrate (320 kbit/s).

In first i had issues with ffmpeg reading way to fast, this was solved with the `-re` parameter.
Before the stream would run way to fast.
Now i think `-re` is my problem, i want to stream the file from second X (using `-ss`) to end but still in real time.
I use it like this:

```
ffmpeg -re -i input.mp3 -ss 19 -f mp3 icecast://source:pass@127.0.0.1:8000/mount
```

But now it reads the first 19 seconds and then starts streaming, but i would wish to start instantly on second 19, no delay (or at least not full 19 seconds)

I hope there is a way, i'm probably overseeing something, a tip would be really helpful.
Thanks in advance, Chris

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution deep in the web:

Setting the `-ss 19` BEFORE the `-i FILE.mp3` did the trick...

Works now with:

```
ffmpeg -re -ss 19 -i input.mp3 -f mp3 icecast://source:pass@127.0.0.1:8000/mount
```